# Checking attached DOM events in Opera

Tags: javascript, events, dom, opera

Is there a way to visualise all currently attached (by any means) DOM events in Opera, or check what events are attached to an element? Kinda like what FF's EventBug or Chrome's Inspector do.

There's [this extension](http://my.opera.com/ilidiomartins/blog/2012/01/31/visual-event-for-opera-extensions), but it has a number of flaws: It's an extension, not native code; From what I understand, it parses scripts and finds code that attaches events, which means it won't find events atached dynamically or it may simply fail to recognize code if the page uses some not very popular framework (see http://jsfiddle.net/pAAKT/); It uses external script to do the actual highlighting; Activating extension also turns all active tabs (and all frames in them) into inspection mode, while it's not possible to exit it in any tab but current...

Answer (score 1):

Opera's Dragonfly offers a way to examine event properties (ex:`onclick`), but not, as of yet, events attached using `addEventListener`. It's a planned feature, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user javascript to log events

```
opera.addEventListener('BeforeEventListener', function(e){ /* log e.event.type and e.event.target for example here */ }, false);
```

This is of course not quite what you're looking for but can be handy for debugging something.